# Copying from StackExchange text to LyX

Tags: math-mode, lyx, conversion

I want to copy some text from MathOverflow, that contains mathematical formulas, to LyX. Currently the text looks like this:

```
So, we have $2r = 2rr+rl$ and $2l = 2ll+rl$.
```

How can I automatically convert all the text between $ symbols to LyX formulas?

Comment: This feature has been [requested](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/3096) for a while (the ticket is 7 years old) and was finally [implemented](http://www.lyx.org/trac/changeset/c14b9e67/lyxgit) by Georg Baum for LyX 2.1. In LyX 2.1 you can go to Edit > Paste Special > Paste From LaTeX. If you happen to use Ubuntu, it's [very easy](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyXOnUbuntu#toc3) to use 2.1beta2 simultaneously with your current version of LyX without any conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you have to do it manually, but in a short way:

- Copy that line and insert it into LyX
- Mark the `$2r = 2rr+rl$` with (!) the two `$`
- hit Insert->Math->Inline

that will convert that expression into inline math code.

Comment: OK, but what do I do if I have tens of them? Is there a way to convert all of them automatically?

Comment: only when they are all in an external file which is then included or as an alternative: Hit CTRL-L and insert the equations as ERT. Looks a bit weird but works

Comment: OK, I put everything inside Ctrl+L and it works, thanks.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi you might also want to put the ERT in an insert > Preview box. This depends on your preference.